# How to speed up repeated sparse matrix solves with `scipy.sparse`?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I am using `scipy.sparse` matrices and `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve` to repeatedly solve matrix equations. The values in the matrix change slightly for every solve, but the sparsity structure and size of the matrix is always the same. Is there a way to take advantage of the uniform structure of all the matrices and speed up the solves?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8227). So imho it's a no (due to scipy; not due to superlu).